# Como destruir minha Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Preciso destruir minha MainActivity quando eu sair do app. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Método **onDestroy():**

**onDestroy()** é chamado quando uma Activity termina seu ciclo de vida. Este método é chamado uma unica vez no clico de vida de uma Activity(atividade).

A melhor solução que achei até o momento, foi essa:

Você pode sobrescrever o método **finish()**, dessa maneira:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    System.out.println("Aplicativo Finalizado!");      
    SaveData();     
    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true) ;          
    super.finish();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

E então invocar o método **onBackPressed()**, dessa maneira:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     this.finish();
    }
```

---

Ou tente somente esse código:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Você não faz isso**. O método `OnDestroy` não serve para destruir sua Activity, mas sim para reagir à destruição dela.

Quem destrói sua Activity é o Android. Tipicamente, o botão "voltar" do aparelho solicita a destruição da Activity ao ser pressionado. O(a) usuário(a) também pode causar a destruição da sua Activity limpando a tarefa associada na tela "Recentes". Além disso, o sistema pode decidir destruir sua Activity se considera que precisa fazer isso para liberar recursos. E, é claro, quando o aparelho desliga.

Se você explicar melhor exatamente o que quer fazer, talvez possa receber uma resposta mais útil.